# How to increase capacity of osrmRoute in osrm package in R

Tags: r, route, open-source-routing-machine

I had plotted the routes of some locations. The maximum number of locations allowed for routing using the OSRM package in R is 100 coordinate points.

How can I extend beyond this restriction?

Comment: It will help if you give some example code that shows it working for 100 points and then failing for 101.

Comment: @Spacedman here is the output from R when you try to work with the osrm package in R for any sets of coordinates larger than 100
.
.


The OSRM server returned an error:
`Error: The public OSRM API does not allow results with a number of durations 
higher than 10000. Ask for fewer durations or use your own server and set its 
--max-table-size option.`

Comment: Also if you try to use the `osrmTrip` function in the `osrm` package, it works for sets of 100 and fails for those above 100.
Here is another example 
`trips <- osrmTrip(loc = day13.crit_spatial_df[c(79,1:100), c("name","long","lat")], overview = "full")` - This worked. But when I had this code below, it failed for 101 - `trips <- osrmTrip(loc = day13.crit_spatial_df[c(79,1:101), c("name","long","lat")], overview = "full")`